# Swapping endianess of parameters in vba

Tags: excel, vba, endianness

I am creating an excel sheet which needs to be capable of taking in a list of parameters (of varying sizes, signed and unsigned) in decimal format, and generating a hex string from this. The problem however is that the parameters within the string need to be little endian, while the string itself will be big endian. I am using VBA  to do this, but I am quite new to it and am running in to difficulty. I think I need to swap the endianess of each parameter before I add it to the string. I have looked about this site and the web and have not found any simple solutions to what im guessing should be a simple problem. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

My code so far for generating the string is shown below:

Sub Generate_String()

```
Dim funcset As String
Dim y As String
x = 0
z = 0
funcset = ""
'while variant column is not empty
Do While ((Trim(Cells(2, 4 + z).Value) <> "") And (Trim(Cells(2, 4 + z).Value) <> "0"))

    Do
        'check if last cell in the column
        If Trim(Cells(4 + x, 1).Value) = "VALUE" Then
            'convert cell contents to hex
             y = Hex(Cells(3 + x, 4 + z).Value)

            'add the converted value to the string
            funcset = funcset + "0x" + y
            x = x + 1

        Else
            'convert cell contents to hex
            y = Hex(Cells(3 + x, 4 + z).Value)
            'add the converted value to the string
            funcset = funcset + "0x" + y + " " 
            x = x + 1

        End If
    ' continue until end of column is reached
    Loop While Trim(Cells(3 + x, 1).Value) <> "VALUE"

    'write the string  to corresponding cell
    Cells(3 + x, 4 + z).Value = funcset
    funcset = ""
    x = 0
    z = z + 1

Loop
```

End Sub

Here is some sample data:
The data has a string generated, but endianess swap has not been done
[image: The data has a string generated, but endianess swap has not been done]

Comment: Your code does not compile as it is (else without if)... Can you show a sample data (source + target output)?

Comment: I cannot follow your code.  However.  Following ` y = Hex(Cells(3 + x, 4 + z).Value)` you have an `End If`.  I assume this is a mistake.  From `funcset = funcset + "0x" + y` I deduce you are used to a language that uses `+` for concatenation.  Replace `+` with `&`.  I agree with assylias, without some example data, no one will be able to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting big-endian into little-endian and vice-versa in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666874/converting-big-endian-into-little-endian-and-vice-versa-in-vba)

Comment: Apologies, was deleting out some comments and test code in my original post and didn't catch it all, I hope it is edited correctly now. I have tried add some sample data in text format but it doesnt appear to format correctly. I added a screenshot instead.  Jean-François I have seen the other post you have mentioned, but I assume there is an easier way of completing the task I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VBA, but here's the algorithm I'd follow.

```
for each parameter in parameter_list
    for i = 1 to (number of bytes in parameter type)
        append 2-character hex value of (parameter mod 256) to string
        parameter = parameter / 256
```

If VBA syntax is similar to Excel function, I think you can add a second parameter, `,2` to your `HEX()` function call to force it to use 2 characters.